# How does keypoint size relate to scale and octave in OpenCV SIFT?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, feature-detection, sift

I'm working with SIFT key-points and I need to know the exact relation between the size of the key-point and the scale (and octave?) where it was detected.

I came across this **size=scale*magnification**, however if this is true why are keypoint sizes floats and not integers? And what exactly is the magnification factor? And does the octave affect the value of the size or just the scale?

Thank you!